# unresolved symbol pthread_create, first referenced in ./armrtk/src/task.obj

Tags: embedded, kernel, rtos, msp432

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now and cannot figure it out. I am using CCS as the IDE and I am working on windows. I am trying to create an RTOS Kernel on a MSP432 and need to use pthreads. I have been able to use pthreads in other examples but I am trying to do my own program and I get this issue when building :

```
unresolved symbol pthread_create, first referenced in ./armrtk/src/task.obj
```

I have included the file path into CCS and I cannot use a .cfg file because I am not using XDCTools. I just need help with this and I greatly appreciate it.
I also get a warning:

```
in pthread_create in TASK.C: #169-D argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *(*)(void *)"
```

TASK.H

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

#include <pthread.h>


struct task_t {
pthread_t* thread;
int threadCheck;
int state;
};

void *task1(void);
void *task2(void);

struct task_t *create_task(void* functionptr);

void delete_task(void *task);

 #endif
```

TASK.C

```
 #include <task.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <pthread.h>

 #define BLOCKED -1
 #define READY 0
 #define RUNNING 1

 int testValue1 = 0;
 int testValue2 = 0;
 struct task_t *new_task;
 pthread_t pntr;

 struct task_t *create_task(void* functionptr) {

     new_task = malloc(sizeof(struct task_t));

     if(!new_task)
        return NULL;

    //set State of the new thread to ready
    new_task->state = 0;
    // check to see if pthread is created
    **new_task->threadCheck = pthread_create(new_task->thread, NULL, functionptr, NULL);**

    if(new_task->threadCheck!= 0){
        //thread failed
        return NULL;
    }

    return new_task;

    }

    void delete_task(void *task) {
        if(task != NULL){
            free(task);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see how you can create an RTOS kernel from pthreads.  AFAIK, most implementations of pthreads (POSIX threads) outside of an actual POSIX OS are a layer above an existing native RTOS.  If pthreads is available, you either already have an RTOS, or the thread support is not real-time capable, and attempting top create an RTOS from it is doomed.  The primary function of an RTOS is multi--threading/tasking so to create an RTOS kernel is necessarily to implement threading - you cannot magically get threading just by including pthreads.h and even then you'd have to link the library.

Comment: _"I have included the file path..."_; What "file path"? To what file?  You understand that pthreads.h _is not_ the library?  You need to link libpthreads.a, but tbh, I doubt that will work; pthreads requires an underlying RTOS to provide thread support; you cannot create an RTOS _from_ pthreads.  You have your chicken before your egg.

Answer (score 0):

The `unresolved symbol` error is a linker error, not a compiler error.  You have failed to link the pthreads library.

With respect to the warning `functionptr` is a `void*` where `pthread_create()` expects a pointer-to-function with signature `void fn(void*)`.

Your task functions have a different signature in any case: `void fn(void)`, so in any event you will need to cast the function pointer in the call to `pthread_create()` (although you are loosing a useful means of passing information into a task function by omiting the `void*` argument).

Modify task.h:

```
typedef void* (*task_t)(void);
struct task_t *create_task( task_t functionptr);
```

The in task.cpp

```
new_task->threadCheck = pthread_create( new_task->thread, 
                                        NULL, 
                                        (void (*)(void *))functionptr, 
                                        NULL ) ;
```

The cast in the `pthread_create()` call alone would supress the warning, but it bad form to pass a function pointer as a generic `void*` since it would prevent the compiler warning you if you were to pass anything other then a function pointer of the expected form to `to the` create_task()`

Comment: How do I go about linking it? I have tried multiple methods and I haven't had any luck. I am using Code Composer Studio. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have tried going to Project -> Properties -> CCS Build and editing the build command from ${CCS_UTILS_DIR}/bin/gmake -j -k -j 4 to ${CCS_UTILS_DIR}/bin/gmake -j -pthread -k -j 4. Is this correct or do I have to do something in Arm Linker.

Comment: @Mperez certainly adding an argument to the gmake command will have no useful effect. As I said in the comment to the question in this target I would expect pthreads to be an optional layer in top of an RTOS, rather than something from which you build an RTOS. I am not familiar with your toolchain or your target, but experience tells me that you are lacking some fundamental concepts you'd need before tackling an RTOS.

Comment: I am lacking some understanding of RTOSes. This was supposed to be my senior project and I had never heard of RTOS until this year. It was a steep learning curve. I thought about steering away from pthreads but my partner had other ideas. I have been trying to figure this out but have been lacking the direction. We are only using the pthreads to contain the tasks, was debating on using OSthreads or even just a task structure and remove the threads in full.

Comment: Thank you. That is the textbook I have been following. I need to take another look and work through it again thank you Clifford. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are on the wrong track.  pthreads is an API for a system's existing native support for multi-threading.  The RTOS _is_ that existing native support.  You need the RTOS before the pthreads (and then you do not really need pthreads - that is just a POSIX compatibility layer for the RTOS).

Comment: So where can I start. I have the textbook but it seems pretty dated. I am using a MSP432 controllers. I am working in CCS they already have pre generated projects but those already have the RTOS implemented. I have been going around this for awhile. And just seem to be stuck. I am assuming I'm going to have to start from scratch again and build up. DO you have any advice? I'd greatly appreciate it. I just want to clarify that I don't need the pthreads. I was using the pthreads as the tasks for the RTOS. Would this not be correct. I guess I would have to develop the Scheduler first.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the questions but I need clarifications and I have not been able to find this or atleast understand it. I really appreciate. I'm super stressed right now and I feel as if it is more complicated than it has to be. I know its a tough subject.

Comment: Clearly that warrants a new question. SO is not a discussion forum and this is not what the comments are for.  What I would say, is that an RTOS is system level code, you won't find the answer in libraries, you necessarily have to get down to the bare metal.  Remember that your MSP342 is an ARM Cortex-M4 and an RTOS kernel can largely be generic to that, so widen your search perhaps.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. I will probably open a new question asking how to get started. I appreciate your help thank you so much.

Comment: @Mperez Careful how you ask such a question, it may easily be voted down or closed for being either to broad or asking for a resource.  You may need to break it down.  You'll need a scheduler that effects context switches to start.  Then you'll need synchronisation, IPC and timing mechanisms.  You need also a means of preventing the scheduler from running when functions that cause rescheduling are called in the interrupt context - the scheduler should run when the interrupt state exits.  As you know there are rather thick books on the subject, which is why it may bee to broad a question.

Comment: The thing you need that makes it an invalid question for SO is https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f0352c0cafe527e86f5bc66?token=  Do not underestimate the size of this task.  There is a reason there is a commercial market for RTOS products - if it were easy, there'd be no value is such libraries.  Also https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/cortex-m-rtos-context-switching, but that uses FreeRTOS as an example, but you can take the principles from it and develop your own.  FreeRTOS is in other respects rather atypical of RTOSes in general.

Comment: I understand. I'll post a question regardless and see if I can curate so information sources to get this started. If possible, take a look at the question and respond to me on there. I would love to get more of your expertise. The book is rather large and it is a broad topic so I am going to try my best to be as concise as possible.

Comment: This is the link to the question. Thank you for your help Clifford.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605286/creating-an-rtos-from-scratch