# Creating an RTOS from scratch

Tags: arm, embedded, rtos, bare-metal

I am in my senior year of college and decided to tackle the task of creating my own RTOS kernel using MSP432 controller. This has proven to be tricky and I would like advice from people who are done this. What is the general layout needed? What was your experience while doing this? I know it may seem like a difficult task but I feel as if I can do it. I will be diving into research tomorrow and trying to expand my knowledge on this. I know this is a broad topic but I'm just asking for alittle advice if possible. Thank you so much. I hope everyone is safe.

Comment: This is too broad of a question to ask here.  If you have a specific technical problem implementing your RTOS, feel free to reduce it to a minimal failing example and you'll be sure to find lots of help.  Until you're at that point, though, you'd do better googling for references or reading things like Jean LeBrosse's uC/OS book

Comment: look at ucos and atom threads and freertos and others, do not try to do this in a vacuum.  Granted do not try to make the kernel/task manager until you are strong at the basics of the chip and processor itself, events, interrupts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to follow one of the course or book. From myself I can recommend this video trainings:

- [Modern Embedded Systems Programming course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPW8O6W-1chwyTzI3BHwBLbGQoPFxPAPM) - great, free, not require hardware, hands-on lessons about embedded systems and programming in C, lessons 22-28 are dedicated for RTOS.
- Series of embedded course [part1](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-the-world-microcontroller-i), [part2](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-the-world-multi-threaded-in), [part3](https://www.edx.org/course/real-time-bluetooth-networks-shape-the-world) - conducted by lecturers from The University of Texas at Austin. Free, based on ARM uC, not require hardware, interesting example and exercises, part3 dedicated for RTOS.

Comment: Do any of those resources discuss _creating_ and RTOS, and required by the question,  or do they merely describe the principles and/or how to use an existing RTOS?  Also "link-to-resource only" type answers are discouraged on SO.  The links can be come stale leaving this a non-answer.  Personally I dislike video resources in any case - they are intrinsically linear, and Mperez will have to wade through hours of that stuff before discovering it was not an answer to his question!